# Raising delegate events in Moq

Tags: c#, delegates, moq

in my moq setup, i want to raise a delegate event. How do i do this?

To be tested:

```
public class SomeClassToBeTested
{
   public void SomeMethodToTest()
   {
      var event = new ThreadStart(someOtherClass.SomeMethod);
      someOtherClass.SomeDelegate += new SomeOtherClass.someDelegate(TriggerMethod);
   }

   public void TriggerMethod()
   {
      // do something 
   }
}
```

Test class:

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
   this.moqSomeOtherClass.Setup(fd => fd.SomeMethod())
                         .Raises(fd => // trigger delgate);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
   this.moqSomeOtherClass.Setup(fd => fd.SomeMethod())
                         .Raises(fd => fd.SomeDelegate +=null);
}
```